# "How many months old" or "how old is your baby"?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

Which one is correct between *How many months old is your baby?* and *How old is your baby?*? Which one is generally used?

Comment: Note: A pet peeve of mine is when people ask how many months old a baby is when they are older than one year old . Having said that, both are grammatically correct, the first one would just be more specific. In addition, both are also frequently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From “How many months old” and “how old is your baby” both the sentences are correct. But, if I say which one is used widely then **“how old is your baby”** is used widely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would say "how many months old is your baby" is also very frequently used, especially when the baby is less than a year old.

Comment: @Inazuma I don't have a baby, but I wouldn't think to specify months. Maybe it's something parents say to one another? I just assume the person answering will give me the answer in the most convenient units.

Comment: @Paul I assure you there are people who don't even think of appropriate units and will give ages in the form of 36 months old. If the baby is fairly newborn you might similarly ask "how many days/weeks?". Of course, this is a much shorter time period relative to when you can ask "how old is he/she?", so it may seem that a unitless question is more common, but I have heard how many months frequently.