# How to answer, how old is your baby?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english, indian-english

My question is how to answer when somebody asks [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86259/how-many-months-old-or-how-old-is-your-baby) question?

Since my baby is 10 months, I just replied **she is 10**, and we laughed out loud. Then I said, **of course, 10 months**.

What is the correct way?

Comment: I noticed that after and retracted the flag. Not sure why it still posted

Comment: downvote? for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"She is 10 months (old)".

We count in months up to 1-year-old.  From then there is mixed usage. It is very common for people to say "She is 18 months old", but you will also hear "She is 1 year and 2 months" or "She is 1 and ¾". For children who are 2 or older we likely to just say "She is 2 (years old)", but sometimes "She is 2 and a half".  For very young babies, their age might be given in days or weeks (or even hours and minutes).

"She is 10" means "She is 10 years old", and never "She is 10 months", even in context.

Answer (score 1):

"She is ten months old" is the answer.

Comment: It is more common to elide the “old” and simply say “she is 10 months”. Kinda how we elide the “years old” in “she is 22 [years old]”.

Comment: @DanBron You think "she is 22" is correct? 22 what? Could be the name of the girl, her specie, anything... Being precise is always better. Jagatha's answer is not wrong, according to me :)

Comment: Jagatha is the correct one but Dan's version is the better version in colloquial language

Comment: @DanBron.you are correct.we can say she is 22 or she is 22 years old but  not  22 years

Comment: @BellaSwan I don’t *think* “she is 22” is correct, I *know* “she is 22” is correct. There are contexts when we would say or write “she is 22 years old” in full, but they are vanishingly rare compared to the frequency with which we say “she is 22”. When learning languages, “correct” is measured by “how similar are your utterances to native speaker’s”, not “how precise are the statements”. You can be hyper-precise but still sound awkward or off, and mark yourself as a non-native speaker. Jagatha, correct, we don’t say “she is 22 years”, which is why the entire phrase “years old” was in brackets.

Comment: @BellaSwan *She's Anna* and *She's human* don't make sense as answers to the question *How old is your baby?*. As an aside, *according to me* is not a natural expression in English, and *specie* doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @userr2684291 That was a joke :)